# Electronic distribution in shells or orbits

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics, atoms

I have read on many websites about the Bohr's model of atom but I couldn't find the reason or prove for why can there be more than one electrons in an orbit or counterproof for one electron in each orbit ( like the one with the  planets in our solar system).

Can anyone give me the reason why there exists more than one electron in an orbit ? Even some of the orbits have 18 or 32 electrons , so don't they affect each other's path ?

**Edit** : does the quantum mechanics give reason for why there can be two electrons in an orbital and not one ?

Comment: The Bohr model has only historical interest. It is not the way to understand atoms. In the Schrodinger model, there are no paths.

Comment: You are confusing orbitals and shells. Also, the same website that told you the an orbital may contain up to two electrons should also in some form explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Bohr's model was extremely inspired for its time, but the modern understanding of quantum mechanics shows that it is flawed in several regards.  Accelerating electric charges radiate electromagnetic waves.  This theoretically implies the orbiting electron should lose kinetic energy and fall into the nucleus.

We know this isn't true, and we require modern quantum mechanics to explain so.  With the advent of quantum mechanics comes our understanding of probabilitistic wavefunctions, the Pauli exclusion principle, and of spin.  There are states (probability distributions that one might associate with the different orbits in Bohr's model) and associated energies with those states.  Pauli exclusion forbids two electrons from sharing the same state, yet due to an intrinsic angular momentum (known as spin) two electron with different spin can.

Most atoms, as you have correctly noted, have many electrons.  Some of these are bound tightly to the nucleus (low energy) while others are of higher energy and can easily participate in chemical reactions.  And there are ways different electrons affect each other -- Coulomb repulsion, for example, will turn the exactly solvable model for hydrogen into something horrific for helium.